# node js mongoose trying to overwrite _id field before saving

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to override the _id field of a mongo doc to an integer with an auto inc.

I've tried some modules and none of them worked for me. I thought I'd write something of my own, like this :

```
productSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this._id = 5; //or what ever
    next();
});
```

but it didn't work and the _`id` field was null. Even tried `this._doc['id'] = 5`. I thought in merging the _id to the doc before it was saved by a redis but that's ugly since the `redis.get` is async so I'd have to pass the save action inside the redis callback.

Any solutions?

Comment: why do I want to overwrite _id? because I don't need a bsonID, it's a unfriendly field and I rather replace by a different field like sql regular id

Comment: I assume it is for friendly URLs.

Comment: You should take  a look here. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

Comment: Did you define `_id` in `productSchema` as a `Number`?

Comment: I did, but I still have to generate an int number for it every time by myself